# password request has expired in magento ver 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, passwords, request, expired-sessions

i have created a whole website on my test server then moved it to client server. After clicking the "Forgot password" option, i got link on my email . When i click on that link it redirects me to reset password  page. Now when I try to reset password it gives me an error "Your password reset link has expired". I tried with the new password it gives message that the "password is invalid" and it is still working with the old password.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created the customer outside the traditional manner , try:

- Enter the login and fill required data.
- Create a new login.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your default email template name: **Forgot Password**
I have same issue for me issue with this email template

In this template find below line

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.rp_customer_id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><span>Reset Password</span></a>
```

and replace with below line:

```
<a href='{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}'><span>Reset Password</span></a>
```

You will see issue with quotes only.

Hope this will help you.